# Bottom 0 is not working On Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, css-position

I have a button with position:fixed and bottom:0; this is fine on every browser but IE 11 - the button is not fixed to the bottom of the viewport, instead, it's suspended slightly above the bottom of the viewport. Any ideas on how to fix this? Below is the code for reference:

```
<!-- The HTML -->
<div class="actions">Actions</div>

/* The CSS */
.actions {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -ms-position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  -ms-position-style: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [a minimal sample to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please include related html and css code. It can really help us to understand the issue in a better way. We can try to check and test your code with the IE 11 browser. With only your description, we can't find out the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou I have updated the question with code sample

Comment: I tested your code in IE and Chrome. The results are the same and I can't reproduce the issue in IE. You could check [the result in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0lQK.png) and [the result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PZ5b.png). Please check if you have missed something and edit your code to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this worked: I simply set the wildcard(*)'s box sizing to content-box, then set overflow of the button div to hidden. And just like that the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reset padding and margins to 0 on the body tag. Also did you set the html tag to have a height of 100%? This may help.